# How to iterate combinations of elements in two arrays in bash?

Tags: bash, loops, iteration, combinations

I have 2 different lists, I have separated these in 2 different files.

```
# cat file1

S1
S2
S3
```

and

```
# cat file2

R1
R2
R3
```

I want to loop over both files, so in first loop, `S1` makes all possible cominations with elements in file2, like this

```
echo "First List Of Combinations"
echo S1 + R1
echo S1 + R2
echo S1 + R3
```

then second combinations

```
echo "Second List Of Combinations"
echo S2 + R1
echo S2 + R2
echo S2 + R3
```

So I decided to put these in two arrays.

```
arr1 = $(cat file1)
arr2 = $(cat file2)
```

what should I read first and what should be incremented? I know this will include 2 while loops reading elements from both arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script should work:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

arr1=$(cat file1)
arr2=$(cat file2)

combinations_counter=1

for i in $arr1
do
  echo "List of combinations #$combinations_counter"
  for j in $arr2 
  do
    echo "$i + $j"
  done
  ((combinations_counter++))
done
```

With the `file1` and `file2` files provided, the result would be:

```
List of combinations #1
S1 + R1
S1 + R2
S1 + R3
List of combinations #2
S2 + R1
S2 + R2
S2 + R3
List of combinations #3
S3 + R1
S3 + R2
S3 + R3
```

Comment: Instead of `arr1=$(cat file1)`, recommend the proper `mapfile -t arr1 <file1
` and lopping arrays is not this way. You are recommending very bad practice.

Comment: @LéaGris I am sorry but I can only recommend what I know. If you think there is a better answer to this question (which I am sure there is), feel free to write your own.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed answer of Bustkiller,

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Properly reading file lines into arrays
mapfile -t arr1 <file1
mapfile -t arr2 <file2

# Iterating the index of arr1
for i in "${!arr1[@]}"
do
  # Properly formatted print-out of combination index with arr1 element
  printf 'List of combinations #%d\n' "$((i + 1))"

  # Iterating the index of arr2
  for j in "${!arr2[@]}"
  do
    # Properly formatting the combinations of elements from both arrays by index
    printf '%s + %s\n' "${arr1[i]}" "${arr2[j]}"
  done
done
# Properly formatting the total computed number of combinations that is:
# number of elements in array1 times number of elements in array2
printf 'Total number of combinations: %d\n' "$((${#arr1[@]} * ${#arr2[@]}))"
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to Arrays and Mapfiles, just 2 loops:

```
while read a  
do  
    while read b  
    do  
        echo $a + $b  
    done < file2  
done < file1
```